# How is the p-value in an OLS regression in statsmodels calculated?

Tags: least-squares, statsmodels

I ran an OLS regression using statsmodels. The summary is as follows.

I am confused looking at the t-stat and the corresponding p-values. For 'var_1' since the t-stat lies beyond the 95% confidence interval (1.375>0.982), shouldn't the p-value be less than 5%?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the 0.975 band"?

Comment: @Dave That's incorrect, because the software reports two-sided CIs.  The critical value for $|t|$ therefore is the $97.5$ percentile of Student's $t$ distribution with 10 DF, equal to $2.23.$  If the reported value of `var_7` were $+0.3024$ then (*caeteris paribus*) its 95% confidence interval would range from $-0.212$ to $0.817$ and its $t$ statistic would equal $+1.309,$ which would still have a P-value of $0.22.$

Comment: I was confused with my previous comment, now deleted since it was incorrect. Since the 95% confidence interval contains 0, the p-value (for a null hypothesis of $0$) will be less than $0.05$.

Comment: @Dave I believe you intended to write "greater than 0.05."

Comment: I sure did...perhaps I should log out of Cross Validated for the rest of the day.